# Get the target element that will be hovered by mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

How can I get the element that will trigger mouseover, when my code was in a mouseout event.

for example:

A is menu, subA is his sub menu, if user's mouse out of A but still over subA, then we should not hide menu A.

Comment: Please, as it's a bit not self-understandable, may we see some code?

Comment: It seems like you've been here long enough to understand that this question is pretty low quality.. can't you post your code and have a *real* description of your scenario?

Comment: I understand the question, possibly because I have had the same requirement myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean what I think you mean, what you want is the [`relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/event.relatedTarget) property of the event in standards-compliant browsers and the [`toElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534684%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property of `window.event` in IE < 9.

jQuery normalizes this to the `relatedTarget` property, so the following will do what you want in all browsers that jQuery supports:

```
$("#yourelement").mouseout(function(evt) {
    alert(evt.relatedTarget.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are fromElement and toElement properties on the event object - these should provide you with the information that you need.

See [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html#mouseover) for more information